# Devise fields inside a password table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Is that possible to setup Devise gem easily with every of its fields inside a passwords table, which is mapped with a Password model belonging to a User model (having just an `email` field)?

In other words, here is a draw of my wanted model design:

```
         +-------+
         | User  |
         +-------+
         | email |
         +-------+
             ^ (have one)
             |
             | (belongs to)
+------------------------+
| Password               |
+------------------------+
| encrypted_password     |
| reset_password_token   |
| reset_password_sent_at |
| sign_in_count          |
| ...                    |
+------------------------+
```

The Devise wiki is very complete, but there's not any info about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a workaround that consists in overriding Devise internal methods (which is a not recommended thing).

However, I haven't tested it well (I only created a user and tried to login), this can introduce some bugs and inexpected behaviour in Devise. So, please, ensure your application is well tested before this code is shipped to production.

The solution to the database authenticatable module consists in:

1. Write the migration

   ```
   class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       create_table(:users) do |t|
         t.string :email

         t.timestamps
       end

       create_table :passwords, :force => true do |t|
         t.integer :user_id
         t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. create a `delegate` that points to `password_record#encrypted_password`.
3. add a `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to `password_record`
4. create a setter for the `encrypted_password` attribute (Devise uses this)

Your models should be like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable

  has_one :password_record, :class_name => "Password", :foreign_key => "user_id"

  delegate :encrypted_password, :to => :password_record

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :password_record

  def encrypted_password=(encrypted_password)
    self.password_record.encrypted_password = encrypted_password
  end

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end


class Password < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I created a user, using this:

```
x = User.new
x.password_record = Password.new
x.password = "123456"
x.email = "a@b.com"
x.save
```

I tested the `sign_in` action and it worked.

You can create using a sign_up form with [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). To check how to do the same things for other modules, take a look at the Devise source code () and see what attributes it uses and how it works (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/lib/devise/models).

Comment: Many thanks, @rodrigo-flores. And thanks for your Devise contributions.